# How to install Ruby 3.1.0 on MacOS Monterey

Tags: ruby, rvm, macos-monterey

I am trying to install Ruby 3.1.0 using RVM on MacOS Monterey, v12.0.1, but it's returning an error while compiling.

I tried updating Homebrew, and uninstalling and reinstalling everything but I am getting the same error.

This is the error in the terminal window:

```
ruby-3.1.0 - #removing src/ruby-3.1.0 - please wait
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/12.0/x86_64/ruby-3.1.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates bundle '/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem' is already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/sindhuja.n/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-3.1.0 - #downloading ruby-3.1.0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-3.1.0 - #extracting ruby-3.1.0 to /Users/sindhuja.n/.rvm/src/ruby-3.1.0 - please wait
ruby-3.1.0 - #configuring - please wait
ruby-3.1.0 - #post-configuration - please wait
ruby-3.1.0 - #compiling - please wait
Error running '__rvm_make -j12',
please read /Users/sindhuja.n/.rvm/log/1643979372_ruby-3.1.0/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

This is the error log file:

```
building .ext/include/x86_64-darwin21/rb_mjit_min_header-3.1.0.h
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `srcs'.
generating transdb.h
transdb.h updated
linking shared-library libruby.3.1.dylib
error in initial header file:
In file included from /var/folders/ky/347m_s3x7d15w435j_pvl2cc0000gn/T/20220204-43863-1rn0v3.c:1:
/var/folders/ky/347m_s3x7d15w435j_pvl2cc0000gn/T/20220204-43863-34xdve.h:7176:66: fatal error: expected identifier or '('
pthread_override_qos_class_end_np(pthread_override_t __override);#pragma clang assume_nonnull end
                                                                 ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [.ext/include/x86_64-darwin21/rb_mjit_min_header-3.1.0.h] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
+__rvm_make:0> return
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and their linked pages. Exactly *what command* did you issue to install Ruby? RVM is powerful, but many of us have switched to [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) because it's less intrusive than RVM. You said you have HomeBrew installed, consider `implode`ing RVM, then let HomeBrew install rbenv then install rbenv's various [plugins](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/wiki/Plugins), and then let it install Ruby. Otherwise carefully read the [RVM installation page](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) and follow it closely.

Comment: I tried installing using the command "rvm install 3.1.0" .  Even I tried installing ruby with rbenv.. again getting the same error.

Comment: Rather than tell us in a comment, you should add responses to comments to your question, editing it then adding the new content as if you'd included it initially. That way, people don't have to read every comment to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error for rbenv 3.1.0 with Monterey12.3beta & Xcode13.3beta.
but once I switched to Xcode13.0, the error's gone.

I guess the error's due to or related to clang version..